# How do I get streamlines from matplotlib into ArcGIS?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am running matplotlib v1.2 with the streamplot.py code to plot streamlines from data in a netcdf file. The plotting is going well but I would like to view the streamlines in Arc so I have been trying to get at the calculated values. I am relatively new to this and spent most of the day yesterday online looking for an answer but haven't seen anything in any forums. From what I can tell Streamplot returns a container object called stream_container which is created using the StreamplotSet class. So stream_container has two attributes(?) (lines and arrows). I assume these two attributes are what I need to get at. I've exhausted my knowledge of Python as well as the two other people I know who know anything about it. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Ultimately I am trying to get it into ArcGIS but as long as I can get at the numbers and manipulate them I am not worried about the moving it over to Arc part. Its the getting at the values in the container object that I am having trouble with.

Please excuse my terminology, I'm relatively new to the programming world.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might look at PyShp--if you are wanting to make shapefiles.  It's pure Python, very easy to use.  But I am not sure I understand your question (I don't have a high enough reputation to comment). You need to get the data for the streamlines into lists or numpy arrays of latitudes and longitudes. "Lines" and "Arrows" sounds like some derivatives from Streamplot (which I am not familiar with).

http://code.google.com/p/pyshp/